# python csv file reading: turning the first row into column headers, next(reader) returns unwanted characters

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Currently I'm writing some code to read in csv files with pandas and I need the first row of the file to be read into a list in order to use it for some descriptives (see code Part1). I can just use the **pandas.read_csv** Parameter `header=0`, which reads out column headers automatically, but it does not return a list afaik. In the comment in `print()`, names is the list that I used to manually pass column headers to **pandas.read_csv** but I'd like to have that be automatic (so when I add/delete columns I don't have to edit the array of names manually).

So, to work around this, I came up with the idea to just separately read in the first row using csv.reader and get a list with column names that I can use in pandas.read_csv that way (see code Part2).

## Part1 pandas csv reading and printing descriptives of the data

```
import pandas as pd
filename = 'test.csv'
dataheadsize = 10
data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";", header=0, decimal=",")
```

## used to pass list of names here instead of header=0

```
print('Descriptives:\n', data.describe(), '\n\n',
'Datasheet (', dataheadsize, 'rows shown):\n', data.head(dataheadsize),
#'Count per class:\n',data.groupby(names[0]).size(),'\n\n',
)
```

## Part2 trying to get the first row of the csv to be read into a list

```
import csv
file = open(filename, 'r')
reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
names = next(reader)
print(names)
```

This gives me the list that I need but for some reason it reads in some additional unwanted characters at index [0]. this is what is returned by `print()`:

```
['ï»¿VAR00001', 'VAR00002', 'VAR00003']
```

As you can see, I don't want those '**ï»¿**' characters to be returned and I wonder what the best method is to circumvent that, and I'd like it to be as automatic as possible for future uses, which is why I don't want to just remove the characters by slicing because I don't know if those characters change depending on the csv file, if the amount of them changes, etc.

As a reference, this is the first 5 rows of the .csv file:

```
VAR00001;VAR00002;VAR00003
1;2;4
1;2;4
0;5;4
0;1;4
```

As you can probably tell by now, I'm not the most experienced coder, so if there's a way to skip the whole 'separately reading in the csv just to get the column names into a list' part, please do let me know, because I couldn't figure that out!

Comment: Seems like an encoding error, could you try with `file = open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')`?

Comment: i suspect the file is encoded in a different format. Try adding the encoding format for example latin will be encoding ='latin1'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `nrows` argument to [`pd.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) to read in column labels separately:

```
# read in column labels as list
cols = pd.read_csv('file.csv', nrows=0).columns.tolist()

# read in data; use default pd.RangeIndex, i.e. 0, 1, 2, etc., as columns
data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None, skiprows=[0])
```

If you need to specify an encoding, you can do so via the `encoding` argument, e.g. `encoding='latin-1'`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason why they add these characters, but why you don't try:

`list(data.keys())`

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails you can manually remove it.

```
def FixHeader(headerArr):
    newHeaderArr = []
    for i in range(len(headerArr)):
        if i == 0: 
            newHeaderArr.append(headerArr[i][1:])
            # 1 being how many chars you want to remove
        else:
            newHeaderArr.append(headerArr[i])
    #print(newHeaderArr)
    return newHeaderArr
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the rapid replies guys!

Just fyi, when I change the encoding to utf-8 I get this list

['\ufeffVAR00001', 'VAR00002', 'VAR00003']

and when I use latin-1 it doesn't change anything compared to the list I originally posted. I'm sure this would work, though, given I figure out the correct Encoding.

However, I'm using list(data.keys()) as it was suggested and that works like a charm while also completely removing the need to read in anything separately. Thanks a bunch to everyone who responded!

Comment: I really think data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";", header=0, decimal=",") 
colnames=list(data.columns) will give you the colum names. can you try?

Comment: yep,list(data.columns) produces the exact same Output as list(data.keys())